# Create The Instance with Ether.js

Tags: typescript, angular, ethernet, ethereum

Получаю ошибку каждый раз, когда пытаюсь создать сущность через библиотеку ether.js 
Имею JSON файл, который я получил после компиляции .sol файла в Remix. Суть в чём? - Я пытаюсь соединиться с метамаском, получить данные с скомпилированого контракта(деплоить буду тоже через Remix) и обновить их, вот код:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ethers } from "ethers";
declare let window: any;

const ethereum = window.ethereum;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public account: string;
  private balance: string;
  public read: string;
  private contractAddr: string;
  private contract: any;
  public message: string;


  constructor() {
    this.account = '';
    this.balance = '';
    this.read = '';
    this.contractAddr = '0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138';
    this.message = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contract = require("../assets/contracts/HelloWorld.json");
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.contract));
  }

  async getAccount() {
     const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
     this.account = accounts[0]; //showAcc

    this.balance = await ethereum.request({
       method: 'eth_getBalance',
       params: [this.account, 'latest']
    })
     //showBalance
    this.read = (parseInt(this.balance) / 10 ** 18).toFixed(5);
  }

  createInstance() {
    return new ethers.Contract(this.contract, this.contractAddr);
  }

  async getData() {
    const helloWorldContract = this.createInstance();
    this.message = await helloWorldContract.methods.message().call();
  }

}
```

Вот ошибка: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 1** 
Скриншот прилагается:
[image]

Вот файл JSON, то что внутри файла, это скопированый ABI с Remix'а.

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
             {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "initMessage",
                "type": "string"
             }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "oldStr",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "newStr",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "UpdatedMessages",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "message",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "newMessage",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "update",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

Comment: Ошибка возникает при парсинге Json-а, я бы посмотрел на сам файлик, чтобы понять что в нем не так

Comment: я даже попробовал использовать JSON, который 100% работал в другом примере, но он то же самое выдаёт. Он в любом случае выдаёт такую ошибку. Я даже пробовал читать через HTTPClient - то же самое

Comment: Попробуй просто в консоль вывести, без JSON.stringify()

Comment: работает с и без, там дело в строке, где создаётся сущность `new ethers.Contract(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была из-за того, что при создании сущности парсилась строка с адресом вместо ABI. Вот объяснение в [документации](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--creating). Таким образом нужно просто поменять местами аргументы в функции `CreateInstance`. Соответственно код должен выглядеть таким образом:

```
createInstance() {
    return new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddr, this.contract.abi, 
        this.signer);
}
```

PS: signer - позволяет не только читать, но записывать, когда provider - только чтение. Это нужно для того, чтобы была возможность апдейтить данные в контракте.